# Extracting xml contents using DOM, how do I separately extract the textcontent of the following childnode

Tags: android

I am extracting xml content using DOM, a particular node "#cdata-section" has the following output that I have attached the logcat output."#cdata-section" its  TextContent is the logcat output. The textcontent has tag elements and I want to separately exact the tag from the output. How I am suppose to do that plz help.

```
xml file=http://myimagefactorycollection.wordpress.com/feed/
 DocumentBuilderFactory DBF=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder Db=DBF.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc=Db.parse(isp);
                Element rootElem=doc.getDocumentElement();
                NodeList itemlist=rootElem.getElementsByTagName("item");
                Node currentitem=null;
                Node childnode=null;
                Node ContentChild=null;
                Node CddatatChild=null;
                NodeList childnodeList=null;
                NodeList CddataList=null;
                NodeList ContentChilList=null;
                for(int i=0;i<itemlist.getLength();i++){
                 currentitem=itemlist.item(i);
                 childnodeList=currentitem.getChildNodes();
                 Log.v("dgd",currentitem.getNodeName());
                    for(int j=0;j<childnodeList.getLength();j++){
                        childnode=childnodeList.item(j);
                          if(childnode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded")){
                             ContentChilList=childnode.getChildNodes();
                             ContentChilList.getLength();
                             CddatatChild=ContentChilList.item(0);
                             CddataList=CddatatChild.getChildNodes();
                              if(CddatatChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("#cdata-section")){    
               output---->      Log.v("dgd",CddatatChild.getTextContent()); 
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
```

Locat Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgHXz.png